# What precautions do you need to take when you change the Jquery version in a standard MVC4 project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I started an MVC4 project and have written quite a bit of code to the standard project the VS2012 interface makes for you. If at this point I want to include a newer version of Jquery and Jquery UI will there be anything affected? My account, shared layout filters/views/ models/ controllers are the same as the Default that VS generates. If I include JS http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js and http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js in my project at this stage will there be any hidden problems that from your experience crop up?

[image]

Comment: How 'bout reading the jQuery upgrade guide? http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say, since we don't know what code you're using.

If you are not using anything that has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 or earlier, then you should have few, if any problems.  jQuery 1.9/2.0 have removed many of the deprecated functions like .live and .die, so if you weren't using those.. you shouldn't have any trouble.  As for jQuery UI, if you're not doing anything in the guts of it, chances are you won't have any problems either.

You probably do not want to upgrade to jQuery 2.0 since that removes support for IE browsers older than IE9, but jQuery 1.9 and jQuery 2.0 are functionally the same other than older browser support.

I would suggest making a copy of you project, doing the upgrade, and seeing if you have any problems.  That is the most direct way to know.